# How do you draw data from a csv file, and then store it is a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that will get a user to input a GTIN-8 product code (done) and then for the program to search for it in a CSV file.

I then want to store the matched product in a variable in python so that I can add up the total cost of an order and display a receipt.

I am having problems getting the program to match the user inputted code with the code and product in the csv file.

Here is what I am trying;

```
def checkfile(code):
    import csv
    with open('products.csv', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            file = open("products.csv", "r")
            line = file.readline()
            #file.close()
            data = line.split(",")
            #if code ==(data[0]):
            if code in reader:
                print("We found your product")
            else:
                print("We couldn't find your product")
                start()
```

The CSV file looks like this;

```
65593691    500 Laminate Sheets 4.5
98593217    200 Sticky Notes    2.5
98693214    Blue Pencil Sharpener   2.1
98693399    500 Sheets of Value Paper   5
```

At the moment, the program just prints 'We couldn't find your product'
I need a way for it to find the product, print it and it's details out, and then store as a variable.

If anyone could help, I'd be very grateful.

Below is the code I have which is ta king the user input, as requested,

```
def start():
    while True:
        code = input("Please enter the product code of a product you wish to "
                      "add to your order:")
        if len(code) == 8:
            for i in code:
                try:
                    int(i)
                    valid = checkvalidity(code)
                except ValueError:
                    print("You have entered an invalid code type. Product codes "
                          "are 8 numbers long. Please try again.")
                    start()
        else:
            print("You have entered an invalid code type. Product codes are "
                  "8 numbers long. Please try again.")
            start()

def checkvalidity(code):
    number = code
    total = (int(number[0]) * 3 + int(number[1]) +
             int(number[2]) * 3 + int(number[3]) +
             int(number[4]) * 3 + int(number[5]) +
             int(number[6]) * 3 + int(number[7]))
    if total % 10 == 0:
        check = 0
        print("Valid.")
        checkfile(code)
    else:
        print("Invalid. Please try again.")
        start()
```

Comment: Please add code showing how you're getting the product code input from the user and calling the function.

Comment: @martineau I have added the code above which I have taking the user input and checking it is a valid GTIN8 product number. Thanks

Comment: Okay, thanks. See my response as a new comment under my answer.

Comment: Regarding your code which gets the user input: `start()` contains an infinite loop and will never return. It's also potentially highly recursive since it may either call itself directly, or indirectly through the `checkvalidity()` function, under the right conditions. This may be related to problem you're having even with the code in my answer for checking for the product code in the file. I suspect you're doing this in order to restart the processing the function performs — which it indeed does, however having the function just call itself is generally a poor way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Life is much easier with pandas.

```
dataframe = pandas.read_csv('file.csv')
```

[Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)

Comment: Suggesting use of the pandas data analysis library package seems like an inappropriate recommendation to give an inexperienced programmer who could very well have problems installing and much less using it — as well as complete overkill for the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a function which *`returns`* the data found, if any, which would be better than storing it in a (global) variable in the function itself.

```
import csv

def checkfile(code):
    found = None
    with open('products.csv', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
             if row[0] == code:
                print("We found your product")
                found = row
                break
        else:
            print("We couldn't find your product")
            start()  # ???
    return found

result = checkfile('98693214')      # -> We found your product
print('result: {}'.format(result))  # -> result: result: ['98693214', 'Blue Pencil Sharpener', '2.1']
result = checkfile('00000000')      # -> We couldn't find your product
print('result: {}'.format(result))  # -> result: None
```

It looks like your csv file is delimited with tab characters, so I specified that.

Comment: Nathan: When I run the code you added to your question that calls it with the version of the function shown in my answer and then enter `98693214` when prompted for a product code, I don't get the results you're reporting. In fact, what happens is it prints `Valid` followed by `We found your product` **eight** times due to the inexplicable `for i in code:` you have in your `start()` function.

Answer (score 0):

`def readFile(f):
     o = open(f) # openFile
     t = o.read()# get raw Text
     l = t.split("\n") # Get lines
     csv = [k.split(",") for k in t.split("\n")] # nested list of table contents`

Now notice that there are options here I think the method you need is something more like this,

`def readFile(f,d):
     o = open(f)
     r = [k.split(d) for k in o.read().split("\n")]
     o.close()
     return(r)`

Where you would need to pass "\t" as d so that python knows to use tab as the delimiter for the lines of the csv file.

sometimes in my projects I will name files with the suffix defined by p:"|" , t:"\t", c:"," where the letter indicates the delimiter psv csv and tsv and sv stands for separated values. But more recently I have just been thinking json.

Answer (score 0):

So, you may have figured this out by now but just in case anyone is still having trouble with it, I just figured it out: Instead of looking for row in *reader*, you should make a new variable (eg called read_lines) that reads through each individual line. Also, I used .read instead of .reader which may make a difference.

```
#use:
reader = csv.read()
read_lines = f.readlines()

#then later:
for row in read_lines
#and
if code in read_lines
```

This will read through each individual line to see if the code appears at all rather than skimming through to see if the code is on its own.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was like this:

```
with open ('Stock File.csv','r') as stock:
    reader=csv.reader(stock, delimiter=',')
barcode=input('Enter the GTIN-8 code of the product you wish to purchase: ')
quantity=int(input('Enter the quantity you wish to purchase: '))
for row in reader:
            if barcode in row:
                cost=float(row[2])
                price=quantity*cost
                total=total+price
                receipt.append(barcode+'    '+row[1]+'    '+str(quantity)+'    '+row[2]+'    '+str(price))
                numofitems=numofitems+1
for i in range(0, numofitems):
            print(str(receipt[i]))
            time.sleep(0.2)
```

The section of my code takes the input and searches for it in the stock file. It then saves the cost of the product as a variable.

I hope I managed to help.

Comment: Do you happen to be doing GCSE Computing this year?